# v8 stacktrace getMethodName vs getFunctionName

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

Whats the difference between getMethodName and getFunctionName for a V8 javascript stacktrace? Hopefully the answer will do better at explaining it than the docs:

https://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/JavaScriptStackTraceApi

Comment: From a quick reading of the docs, I’ll say it’s `var obj = {foo: function bar() {}};` — `getMethodName` would get `foo` or `obj.foo` or something, and `getFunctionName` would get `bar`. (Can’t actually try it right now, of course…)

Comment: Sounds right, test it and write it up as an answer and you got a check mark ; )